# Achieving ACID properties using JDBC?

Tags: jdbc

First of all i would like to confirm is it the responsibility of developer to follow these properties or responsibilty of transaction Apis like JDBC?

Below is my understanding how we achieve acid properties in JDBC

Atomicity:- as there is one transaction associated with connection, so we do commit or rollback , there are no partial updation.Hence achieved

Consitency:- when some data integrity constraint is voilated (say some check constraint) then sqlexception will be thrown . Then programmer acieve the consistent database by rollbacking the transaction?

one question on above say  we do transaction1 and sql excpetion is thrown during transaction 2 as explained above . Now we catch the exception and do the commit will first transaction be commited?

Isolation:- Provided by JDBC Apis.But this leads to the problem of concurrent update . so it has be dealt manually right?

Durability:- Provided by JDBC Apis.

Please let me if above understanding is right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ACID principles of transactional integrity are implemented by the database not by the API (like JDBC) or by the application.  Your application's responsibility is to choose a database and a database configuration that supports whatever transactional integrity you need and to correctly identify the transactional boundaries in your application.

When an exception is thrown, your application has to determine whether it is appropriate to rollback the entire transaction or to proceed with additional processing.  It may be appropriate if your application is processing orders from a vendor, for example, to process the 99 orders that succeed and log the 1 order that failed somewhere for users to investigate.  On the other hand, you may reject all 100 orders because 1 failed.  It depends what your application is doing.

In general, you only have one transaction open at a time (or, more accurately, one transaction per connection).  So if you are working in transaction 2, transaction 1 by definition has already completed-- it was either committed or rolled back previously.  Exceptions thrown in transaction 2 have no impact on transaction 1.

Depending on the transaction isolation level your application requests (and the transaction isolation levels your database supports) as well as the mechanics of your application, lost updates are something that you may need to be concerned about.  If you set your transaction isolation level to read committed, it is possible that you would read a value as 'A' in transaction 1, wait for a user to do something, update the value to 'B', and commit without realizing that transaction 2 updated the value to 'C' between the time you read the data and the time you wrote the data.  This may be a problem that you need to deal with or it may be something where it is fine for the last person to update a row to "win".

Your database, on the other hand, should take care of the automatic locking that prevents two transactions from simultaneously updating the same row of the same table.  It may do this by locking more than is strictly necessary but it will serialize the updates somehow.